# Murmur Hash 3 in python

Tags: python, hash

I'm trying to implement murmur hash 3 in python. I have confusion with this function `mmh3.hash_bytes(key)`.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
a = bitarray()
print(mmh3.hash('A')) # output is 1423767502 a hash value
```

Next, I tried one more function

```
print(mmh3.hash_bytes('A')) 
# output is b'z\xb1)\x9a\xb7\xc2_\x037\x99\xddF\x9c\xf2}8'
```

The output of mmh3.hash_bytes('A') confuses me. Shouldn't both functions have the same value? Because both hash value 'A'. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What is `mmh3`? It's not part of the standard library. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris Nah it's not part of the standard library. you have to install it to use it.

Comment: Right, so... what is it? Is it [this](https://pypi.org/project/mmh3/)? Again, please read [ask], paying particular attention to the part about pretending you're talking to a busy colleague. We shouldn't have to guess at this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

From the [online documentation](https://pypi.org/project/mmh3/) :

> `mmh3.hash("foo") # returns a 32-bit signed int`
> [...]
> `mmh3.hash_bytes("foo") # 128 bit value as bytes`

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) says the same thing :

> The current version is MurmurHash3, which yields a 32-bit or 128-bit hash value.

This is also explicit in the [header file of the C++ implementation](https://github.com/hajimes/mmh3/blob/master/MurmurHash3.h) :

> `void MurmurHash3_x86_32  ( const void * key, Py_ssize_t len, uint32_t seed, void * out );`
> `void MurmurHash3_x86_128 ( const void * key, Py_ssize_t len, uint32_t seed, void * out );`

Same for the tests that verify that it is different ([1](https://github.com/hajimes/mmh3/blob/master/test_mmh3.py#L21), [2](https://github.com/hajimes/mmh3/blob/master/test_mmh3.py#L185)) :

> `assert mmh3.hash("foo") == -156908512`
> [...]
> `assert mmh3.hash_bytes("foo") == b"aE\xf5\x01W\x86q\xe2\x87}\xba+\xe4\x87\xaf~"`

So I admit that it can be surprising that the same hash function returns two different results, but actually it is not exactly the same hash function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why they are different is simple in modern cryptography; domain separation so that different sized calls to MurmurHash ([SHA2 has it and SHA3 derived has it, too](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83307/18298)) will output different values. This may prevent some attacks in the Cryptographic case (MurmurHash is not cryptographic hash) or help to diverge the tables in some attacks...

[A nice definition from  Hashing to Elliptic Curves](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-05#page-8)

> Cryptographic protocols that use random oracles are often analyzed
> under the assumption that random oracles answer only queries
> generated by that protocol.  In practice, this assumption does not
> hold if two protocols query the same random oracle.  Concretely,
> consider protocols P1 and P2 that query random oracle R: if P1 and P2
> both query R on the same value x, the security analysis of one or
> both protocols may be invalidated.
>
> A common approach to addressing this issue is called domain
> separation, which allows a single random oracle to simulate multiple,
> independent oracles.  This is effected by ensuring that each
> simulated oracle sees queries that are distinct from those seen by
> all other simulated oracles.  For example, to simulate two oracles R1
> and R2 given a single oracle R, one might define
>
> R1(x) := R("R1" || x)    R2(x) := R("R2" || x)
>
> In this example, "R1" and "R2" are called domain separation tags;
> they ensure that queries to R1 and R2 cannot result in identical
> queries to R.  Thus, it is safe to treat R1 and R2 as independent
> oracles.

If we look at the code sample from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) we will see this line;

`hash ← hash XOR len`

that is the desired length (`len`) is incorporated into MurmurHash so that the value will change instead of simple truncation of the 128-bit output.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion you're experiencing is due to the difference in the outputs of the `mmh3.hash()` and `mmh3.hash_bytes()` functions in the mmh3 library.
The `mmh3.hash()` function returns a 32-bit signed integer hash value, while the `mmh3.hash_bytes()` function returns the hash value as a byte string.
In your example, `mmh3.hash('A')` returns the hash value 1423767502, which is a 32-bit signed integer.
On the other hand, `mmh3.hash_bytes('A')` returns the byte string b'z\xb1)\x9a\xb7\xc2_\x037\x99\xddF\x9c\xf2}8'. This byte string represents the same hash value, but in a different format.
To compare the two outputs, you can convert the byte string to an integer using the `int.from_bytes()`

```
import mmh3
hash_value = mmh3.hash('A')
print(hash_value)  # Output: 1423767502

byte_string = mmh3.hash_bytes('A')
hash_value_from_bytes = int.from_bytes(byte_string, byteorder='big', signed=False)
print(hash_value_from_bytes)  # Output: 1423767502
```